# SQL Server Migration assistant

Tags: migration, azure-sql-database

I an trying to migration tables from a MS Access database (local drive) to SQL Azure.  The issue is that when I select the access database SQL Server Management assistant shows 0/0 tables.  I can open the database locally and there are 8 tables.  Not sure why SQL Server Migration Assistant does not see any of the tables in the access database.

I am using version 6.0 of SQL server Migration Assistant.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you checked the resource [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313061(v=sql.110).aspx) about preparing the access database for migration. It is possible that there are some incompatible features or settings in the Access database that is preventing SSMA to work.

Are there any error messages in the log file? You can find it at "%APPDATA%\Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant\Access\log\ssma.log". Can you post any relevant information here?